# Taking long time to load random images

Tags: php, performance

I have a random image generator for my site. The problem is, it takes a really long time.. I was wondering if anybody could help to speed it up in any ways. The site is http://viralaftermath.com/, and this is the script:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg;');
$images = glob("images/" . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
echo file_get_contents($images[array_rand($images)]);
```

Comment: yes. get rid of that glob and read the images from a database list or at the very least parse a text file.

Comment: @Kai `glob()` is generally not a huge bottleneck, not until you hit tens of thousands of files in a directory. The general architecture of the script is a much more grave problem.

Comment: Did you profile your code? Then tell us which method takes significant time.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty resource-intensive way to do this, as you are passing the image data through PHP and not specifying any caching headers, so the image has to be reloaded every single time you open the page.

A much better approach would be to have `glob()` list the files *within the HTML page that you're using to embed the image.* Then randomize that list, and emit an `<img>` tag pointing to the actual file name that you determined randomly.

When you are linking to a static image instead of the PHP script, you also likely benefit from the web server's caching defaults for static resources. (You could use PHP to send caching headers as well, but in this scenario it really makes the most sense to randomly point to static images.)

```
$images = glob("images/" . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE); 

# Randomize order
shuffle ($images);

# Create URL
$url = "images/".basename($images[0]);

echo "<img src='$url'>";
```

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: Still pretty laggy. I'll just use colours.

Comment: @Tayler there may be other issues at play then - how large are the images?

Comment: @Markus I did not say that. I said he's not currently doing it. You could do it from PHP, but the whole pass-through approach is pointless anyway.

Comment: @Markus please tell me which sentence creates that appearance for you. "You are not specifying any caching headers" != "PHP cannot specify caching headers"

Comment: Yeah, my fault. I understood it wrongly after reading it first. It's 2am here in BKK and I had a few beers ;) I'll delete my comment.

Comment: @Markus fair enough. But I'll edit it to make it clearer that you *can* generally send caching headers with PHP

Answer (score 0):

Profile your code and find the bottlenecks. I can only make guesses.

```
echo file_get_contents($file);
```

This will first read the complete file into memory and then send it to the output buffer. It would be way nicer if the file goes directly into output buffer. [`readfile()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) is your friend. It would be even better to avoid buffering completely. [`ob_end_flush()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php) will help you there.

A next candidate is the image directory. If searching for one image takes a significant time, you have to optimize that. This can be achieved by an index (e.g. with a database).

Comment: How would you cache a resource that always has the same name, but will by design contain a different image on every request? Also the idea of passing these images through PHP is inane in the first place

Comment: But every response is designed to serve a different random image. I don't see how ETag will help (except for the super rare case where the randomizer happens to show two identical values in a row) . The only sensible approach is to point to a random resource with a distinct URL.

Comment: True, HTTP caching doesn't make any sense at all.